# How to bring list of relational tables used in DSV of SSAS

Tags: ssas

Is there anyway   to  know underlying relational tables and their Column used in dsv . Manually we go to DSV and check tables , but it tedious process when  Cube is large .

This is useful to check   Impact  of changes in Relational tables on Measures

For Example :  IF there is   measure called [Measure]. [Number of Sales] , then I would like to  see DSV and  respective Relational tables  .

Answer (score 0):

Would the [Used Columns Report](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/ColumnUsageReports/) in BIDS Helper be what you are looking for?

It is an open source project so if for security reasons you can't install it, compile the whole project yourself. Or at least grab the relevant code and put that snippet in your own project. Here is the relevant [code](https://github.com/BIDeveloperExtensions/bideveloperextensions/blob/bidshelper-vsix/SSAS/UnusedColumnsPlugin.cs).

Comment: Hi Greg,   Sorry for rate reply. we have restrictions  to install these softwares .   I could  able  run code to  extract Dsv Name and its related queries from  Cube ..    Using this dataset , I could able to parse depended columns and names of relational tables .  Now  my goal is to link  Dsv and   Measuregroup ...